# Storing Word and other documents in WSO2 G-REG

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Among many features of WSO2 G-REG listed [here](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/) there is one which states that in G-REG you can "store any type of data or metadata" (etc. Word documents). How to do that? Because I don't see any options to do that in a management console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Users are provided to add common service information through standard
>   service metadata formats like using WSDL (Web Services Description
>   Language) files, Policy file and schema files. User have to give the
>   location of their WSDL, Policy or Schema files from local file system
>   or as a URL, Governance Registry is importing those information in to
>   Registry as resources. All the special resources are having their own
>   Media Type which will be useful to users to handle them convenience
>   way.

For more information, check the documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Governance+Artifacts) and [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Managing+Documents)

Comment: Thanks, I am using G-REG 5.0.1, so as I see Documents are a new feature in G-REG 5.1.0

Comment: This link https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Managing+Documents says that "Page Deleted", so as I understood there is no new feature for documents.